# IBM Worklight - Deployment issue from Local Worklight Studio to Device

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I have worklight app project on my local, one of my colleague has already deploy app on Worklight Server 6.1, he provided me apk and ipa both, I have installed ipa in my iPhone.

Now when I do some changes in the code for that app and deploy it doesn't give me update in my iPhone, i tried another android device but the update is not coming on that also, This work perfectly when I access my browser console (server console) for that app. but for device its not working

I have worklight studio 6.1, Server 6.1. While deploying i am giving correct URL and context, and on server console updating .wlapp for all environment.

I checked with my colleague and he is doing same step and when he updates something and deploy it works but when I do it doesn't

Please let me know what I am missing here

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation has many holes in it, making it difficult to understand your scenario. You need to explain it better and with far more detail about your environment, about your colleague's environment, about how s/he and you are building the project and where to you are deploying it.

**Edit** your question with the above.

---

Trying to understand what you wrote... do you mean that:

1. You have some Worklight project in your local Worklight Development Server (Worklight Studio).
2. You provide the project to your colleague who does... what with it? builds it? Where? in his OWN Worklight Development Server? and then provides you the .ipa and .apk?

To where does you colleague point the app? to his own server?
If you install an .ipa or .apk that points to server X (your colleague's) and the you build it again, in your own server, and **do not** point it to server X as well (AND deploy the .wlapp **in server X**), you will never get the update in the device.

You need to make sure what is the serving Worklight Server for the application.
You need to make sure to build the application and deploy it for that server.

This you set-up in Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target.
You need to then Run As > Build application, and the deploy the generated .wlapp to server X

Then, the installed app will receive an update.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it well, So my colleague created this project and build, deploy it on our Cloud Server, say Server X , in build and deploy target he gave http://198.176.00.000:9080 and in Context path he gave /App1, he gave me ipa and apk both from he local which is pointing to Server X, I took project from SVN and build it and deploy on the same above URL and did build application and deploy on the same server X, but still its not giving update on device

Comment: So you must verify that in your Eclipse, after making changes in the app web resources, the the building is not done locally - you must set it in your environment to the same external server > build > deploy the .wlapp In the remote server.

Comment: When I go to my Worklight Build and Deploy Target I have that checkbox checked for builde application for different server and i am using correct Server and Context path and I can see changes when I use Desktop Browser after I upload .wlapp from server console, but on device I don't get update neither my code changes, Also in iPhone I checked in app setting that its pointing to the same server.

Comment: Please define what is "cloud server".

Comment: Cloud Server means just our company production Worklight Server 6.1 which has this URL 198.176.00.000:9080 ( I just changed last part to 00000), our app is pointing to this, I give this URL in my Target, I go to this URL and upload/deploy my wlapp